# What's a good way to grab data from an MPEG Transport Stream file to use within a script?

Tags: mpeg

I've recently started to use tsduck, which I know can give me information about each and every packet within a ts file. But when I pipe the output to a text file, its way too much data and crashes often when I am trying to view it. Similarly, if i were to read that file into a script for e.g a Python script, it just seems so slow and sluggish, especially for long duration HD content where the number of ts packets will go into the millions.

Yes utilities like tsduck has its uses, but I have some very specific things I want to find out about the stream for e.g how consistent is PAT and PMT, or if continuity indictors are present... the list goes on.

Yes there are tools out there like Manzanita that gives this information, but what if you wanted to create your own script to do these things?

So the question is, what's a good way to grab data from an MPEG transport stream file such that you can use a script to analyse the data?

Comment: Thank you. Well I already have sat down and started, this is exactly why I'm trying to read data from an mpeg TS file. I'm not an expert, and this is why I'm asking questions because I want to learn. If I can't figure out how to even read data from a TS file, how can I continue?

Comment: Ok I will start with that. Yes you posted source code, but I don't know C++. It's a bit like someone giving you a novel in Japanese and asking you to write your own, even though you've not studied Japanese. I will start with what you've said though, so don't think I'm being ungrateful, just explaining perspective.

Comment: I think I need to explain a little further. I have not been trying to write a parser for a year. The desire to write a parser has been recent. But what about all those questions you've been helping with for over a year you ask? Well, on occasion here and there I've had to work on a few things so I've asked where I was not sure. Once upon a time I asked if ffprobe gives frame information in decode or presentation order. You replied presentation order. This is code I wrote from your help: https://github.com/BabaSar/MaxConsecutiveBPictures/blob/master/maxConsecBPictures.py